# Clone file input on Change event clone x2 all inputs

Tags: jquery

I want to clone a new file input from the first one everytime value change got fired.

I tried unsuccessfully to make this works.

It works on first event change, but on second time it clones x2 input file (so I got 4 files input) and 8 files input on third time, and so on ...

Thank you very much for your help

```
<div class="inputs-wrap">
   <label>Proposez Des Photos :</label>
   <input type="file" name="image[]" accept="image/*" class="file-input" />
</div>

$('.file-input').bind('change', function() {
    var ext = $(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {
        $(this).val('');
        $('#error-form').html('Seuls les formats images sont acceptés').show();
    } else {
        $('.file-input:first').clone(true).insertAfter('.file-input');
    }
});
```

Comment: Post your HTML please. Also, a jsFiddle.net example can be helpful.

Comment: Instead of doing `$('.file-input:first').clone()` why not just use `$(this).clone()` so it only clones that 1 element whose input has been changed?

Comment: this is the very first thing I did, it makes same things
It's like the event change is fired that there much file input after clone
I'll do fiddle tomorrow morning if the problem is hard to be find
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the selector in your insertAfter to ".file-input:last"

```
$('.file-input:first').clone(true).insertAfter('.file-input:last');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6PYew/

Comment: That should do it. To elaborate on why this works for the OP is because he was inserting after every class of `file-input`

Comment: yeah,
this looks like a jQuery defect to me.

Comment: Really depends on your application. In some cases it may be useful.

Comment: I guess you're right. i was confusing this with a "move" function.

Comment: It works great, thanks for this and thanks for the explication